# looping through parameters in angular 4 (typescript) constructor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In an angular 4 model, I have some typescript code that looks like this:

```
export class Thing {
  public a: number;
  public b: number;
  public c: number;
  constructor(a, b, c){
    this.a = a || 0;
    this.b = b || 0;
    this.c = c || 0;
    }
}
```

This seems an obvious place to use a loop, or something simpler than declaring variables a, b, and c and then following up with assigning a, b, and c, via the constructor.

Not sure how to get that done though.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this. Declare your variables via *access modifiers* in the constructor. This will automatically create your fields with that access modifiers and *assign* to them the values which you pass. Also you can assign *default values* to the parameters, if the value passed will be `undefined`.

```
export class Thing { 
   constructor(public a: number = 0, 
               public b: number = 0, 
               public c: number = 0) {

   }
}

const thing = new Thing(1, 2);
// thing.a = 1
// thing.b = 2
// thing.c = 0 - default value
```

One Note also. [**Angular 5**](https://angular.io/) is released. You can use it.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that that's solution I'm most after.  And yes, I'm also on angular 5 right now. My miss type.